# Python - function won't return

Tags: python, return, function

I'm learning Python and have a problem. It is all about defining functions. Maybe I don't understand the return function...

```
def adding(x, y):
    tuple1 = ()
    ans = x + y
    tuple1 = tuple1 + (ans,)
    return tuple1

adding(3, 2)
tuple1
```

When I run this in Python, it proceeds with the `adding(3, 2)`, but won't show me the `tuple1` (even if I print it...), it says that `tuple1` is not defined, why is that? I thought that return will return the calculated object and store it in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tuple1` is a local name in the `adding()` function. You need to store the return value of the function in a *new* name:

```
return_value = adding(3, 2)
```

Now you can use `return_value` to see what object was returned from `adding()`.

You can even `tuple1` instead of `return_value` there, but it'll only *look* the same as the name used in `adding()`. Outside the function, names are part of a different *scope*, and are independent of the local names used inside functions (although names in functions *can* refer to the same things as the module, or global scope).